# Minecraft (Java Edition) Modded Version of MC 1.9, Minecraft launching crash

Tags: java, arrays, minecraft, minecraft-forge

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2

When I start the modded version of mc 1.9 the game starts normally. But after a few seconds the game crashes and the launcher pops up with this error message... Can someone say what I should do next or how I can solve this. Its very important...

I have the latest JAVA version

Comment: You may add the minecraft tag to your question

Comment: To analyse the error better, some crash reports are required

Comment: It is not good to have the latest version of Java installed for minecraft. Minecraft works with java 8.

Comment: The latest supported version of Forge is 1.14. Upgrade to a newer version. Also, StackOverflow is not the place to ask these questions - you are asking why some software crashes, not why some software _you have written_ crashes.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to narrow down to what mod is causing the problem. Restart MC with each mod in your mod folder. It is likely an incompatibility between mods causing the problem. You can also check for known mod incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft works with java 8. Not with the latest java version. Try uninstalling all java versions and installing java 8. Also, hand over a log and crash report, would be really useful.